# MongoDB fails in non-busy hours

Tags: cache, mongodb

I am running a cron job that queries some data from MongoDB during the night, when nobody else is using MongoDB to read or write data, and I get this error
`Error: server.lab:27017: Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for 30.000000 seconds`
During the day the query lasts about 60 ms to return data.
I have enough RAM, and even doubling it doesn't help.
MongoDB is running on XFS file system. I use version 3.2.3 (newest).
I know that MongoDB uses linux cache, and most probably the problem is the warming up mechanism of MongoDB.
What else I can do?

Here is the query.

```
db.event.aggregate([
{
     $match : {"schedule.sessions.attendance.0" : {$exists : true}}
},
{
    $unwind : "$schedule"
},
{
    $unwind : "$schedule.sessions"
},
{
    $project : {
    '_id' : false,
    'schedule.sessions.date_start' : 1,
    'schedule.sessions.date_finish' : 1,
    'schedule.sessions.attendance' : 1
    }
},
{
    $match : {
        "schedule.sessions.attendance.0" : {$exists : true},
        'schedule.sessions.date_start' : {$gte : ISODate("2016-02-14T20:00:00.000+0000"), $lt : ISODate("2016-02-15T20:00:00.000+0000") }
    }
}

])
```

event collection contains about 5000 documents.

And here is the structure of the document

```
mongos> db.event.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("563cc6993764872c268b45db"),
    "schedule" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("563cc6993764872c268b45d7"),
            "sessions" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5694d3c842600772f64bcc1a"),
                    "date_start" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:30:00Z"),
                    "date_finish" : ISODate("2016-02-08T13:30:00Z"),
                    "place" : [ ],
                    "attendance" : [
                        ObjectId("55ed6d03b3b852c812003b92"),
                        ObjectId("55ed6ce1b3b852c8120023f2"),
                        ObjectId("55eee520b3b852ac930003cb"),
                        ObjectId("55ed6cfdb3b852c812003722"),
                        ObjectId("55ed6d01b3b852c812003a52"),
                        ObjectId("55ed6d01b3b852c812003a7d")
                    ],
                    "date_created" : null,
                    "date_updated" : null,
                    "shard_location_id" : null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("563cc6993764872c268b45d8"),
            "sessions" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5694d3c842600772f64bcc1b"),
                    "date_start" : ISODate("2016-02-15T11:30:00Z"),
                    "date_finish" : ISODate("2016-02-15T13:30:00Z"),
                    "place" : [ ],
                    "attendance" : [
                        ObjectId("55ed6d03b3b852c812003b92"),
                        ObjectId("55ed6ce1b3b852c8120023f2"),
                        ObjectId("55eee520b3b852ac930003cb"),
                        ObjectId("55ed6cfdb3b852c812003722"),
                        ObjectId("55ed6d01b3b852c812003a7d")
                    ],
                    "date_created" : null,
                    "date_updated" : null,
                    "shard_location_id" : null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("563cc6993764872c268b45d9"),
            "sessions" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5694d3c842600772f64bcc1c"),
                    "date_start" : ISODate("2016-02-22T11:30:00Z"),
                    "date_finish" : ISODate("2016-02-22T13:30:00Z"),
                    "place" : [ ],
                    "attendance" : [ ],
                    "date_created" : null,
                    "date_updated" : null,
                    "shard_location_id" : null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("563cc6993764872c268b45da"),
            "sessions" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5694d3c842600772f64bcc1d"),
                    "date_start" : ISODate("2016-02-29T11:30:00Z"),
                    "date_finish" : ISODate("2016-02-29T13:30:00Z"),
                    "place" : [ ],
                    "attendance" : [ ],
                    "date_created" : null,
                    "date_updated" : null,
                    "shard_location_id" : null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b9d21c376487714d2c1c0a"),
            "sessions" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("56b9d21c376487714d2c1c09"),
                    "date_start" : ISODate("2016-02-14T11:30:00Z"),
                    "date_finish" : ISODate("2016-02-14T13:30:00Z"),
                    "place" : [ ],
                    "attendance" : [
                        ObjectId("55ed6d03b3b852c812003b92"),
                        ObjectId("55ed6ce1b3b852c8120023f2"),
                        ObjectId("55eee520b3b852ac930003cb"),
                        ObjectId("55ed6cfdb3b852c812003722"),
                        ObjectId("55ed6d01b3b852c812003a7d")
                    ],
                    "date_created" : null,
                    "date_updated" : null,
                    "shard_location_id" : null
                }
            ],
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-09T11:48:44.400Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-09T11:48:44.400Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : null
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b9d24c376487794e2c1c0a"),
            "sessions" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("56b9d24c376487794e2c1c09"),
                    "date_start" : ISODate("2016-02-21T11:30:00Z"),
                    "date_finish" : ISODate("2016-02-21T13:30:00Z"),
                    "place" : [ ],
                    "attendance" : [ ],
                    "date_created" : null,
                    "date_updated" : null,
                    "shard_location_id" : null
                }
            ],
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-09T11:49:32.324Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-09T11:49:32.324Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : null
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b9d2583764870e4e2c1c0b"),
            "sessions" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("56b9d2583764870e4e2c1c0a"),
                    "date_start" : ISODate("2016-02-28T11:30:00Z"),
                    "date_finish" : ISODate("2016-02-28T13:30:00Z"),
                    "place" : [ ],
                    "attendance" : [ ],
                    "date_created" : null,
                    "date_updated" : null,
                    "shard_location_id" : null
                }
            ],
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-09T11:49:44.108Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-09T11:49:44.108Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : null
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c47ff416d37ce33f1e8144"),
            "sessions" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("56c47ff416d37ce33f1e8143"),
                    "date_start" : ISODate("2016-03-06T11:30:00Z"),
                    "date_finish" : ISODate("2016-03-06T13:30:00Z"),
                    "place" : [ ],
                    "attendance" : [ ],
                    "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-17T14:13:08.652Z"),
                    "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-17T14:13:08.652Z"),
                    "shard_location_id" : null
                }
            ],
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-17T14:13:08.652Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-17T14:13:08.652Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : null
        }
    ],
    "subscription" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56af42ff16d37c4901afc81d"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6d00b3b852c8120039e7"),
            "status" : "approved",
            "type" : NumberLong(2),
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:35:27.324Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:35:27.324Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56af441958f591da05954741"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55eee515b3b852ac9300024a"),
            "status" : "approved",
            "type" : NumberLong(2),
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:40:09.034Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:40:09.034Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56af44b6f5417201179f6822"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6cfcb3b852c8120036b5"),
            "status" : "approved",
            "type" : NumberLong(2),
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:42:46.296Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:42:46.296Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56af450d16d37cb20aafc83c"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6d03b3b852c812003b92"),
            "status" : "approved",
            "type" : NumberLong(2),
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:44:13.048Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:44:13.048Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56af4543f541728c1a9f67d5"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6ce9b3b852c812002924"),
            "status" : "approved",
            "type" : NumberLong(2),
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:45:07.372Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:45:07.372Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56af458a16d37cb20aafc8c1"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6cffb3b852c812003912"),
            "status" : "approved",
            "type" : NumberLong(2),
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:46:18.765Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:46:18.765Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56af4612f54172991d9f67f5"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6cd6b3b852c812001b93"),
            "status" : "approved",
            "type" : NumberLong(2),
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:48:34.755Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:48:34.755Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56af45f116d37c680fafc8e3"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6cfdb3b852c812003723"),
            "status" : "approved",
            "type" : NumberLong(2),
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:48:01.395Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:48:01.395Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56af46bc16d37c2f11afc8ac"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55eee513b3b852ac9300020a"),
            "status" : "approved",
            "type" : NumberLong(2),
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:51:24.653Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:51:24.653Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56af46e2376487b31fa41f34"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55eee519b3b852ac930002ca"),
            "status" : "approved",
            "type" : NumberLong(2),
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:52:02.953Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:52:02.953Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56af4756f5417214259f67c0"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6ce1b3b852c8120023f2"),
            "status" : "approved",
            "type" : NumberLong(2),
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:53:58.595Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:53:58.595Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56af477af5417261259f67c3"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55eee520b3b852ac930003cb"),
            "status" : "approved",
            "type" : NumberLong(2),
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:54:34.308Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:54:34.308Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56af478e376487a822a41f52"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6d04b3b852c812003c02"),
            "status" : "approved",
            "type" : NumberLong(2),
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:54:54.084Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-01T11:54:54.084Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b87f27f54172375e7b23cb"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6ce1b3b852c812002389"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:42:31.240Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:42:31.240Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(60074372)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b87f27f54172375e7b23cc"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6cdcb3b852c81200202d"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:42:31.269Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:42:31.269Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(85072479)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b87f27f54172375e7b23ce"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6cdab3b852c812001ea6"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:42:31.299Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:42:31.299Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(54819081)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b87f27f54172375e7b23cf"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6cdbb3b852c812001fba"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:42:31.331Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:42:31.331Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(65625871),
            "status_deleted" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b87f27f54172375e7b23d0"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6ce9b3b852c812002929"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:42:31.360Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:42:31.360Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(79641334)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b87f27f54172375e7b23d1"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6cfab3b852c812003504"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:42:31.388Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:42:31.388Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(94737821)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b8806df5417242647b23c7"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6cfeb3b852c812003845"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:57.320Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:57.320Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(66955040)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b8806df5417242647b23c8"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6cfab3b852c812003596"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:57.349Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:57.349Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(83983525)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b8806df5417242647b23c9"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6d00b3b852c8120039ac"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:57.544Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:57.544Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(70202545),
            "status_deleted" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b8806df5417242647b23ca"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6d03b3b852c812003b98"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:57.572Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:57.572Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(83981351)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b8806df5417242647b23cb"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6cfdb3b852c812003722"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:57.630Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:57.630Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(68552635)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b8806df5417242647b23cc"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6cffb3b852c812003894"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:57.748Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:57.748Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(80433985)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b8806df5417242647b23cd"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6cfbb3b852c8120035ed"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:57.957Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:57.957Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(67251008)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b8806ef5417242647b23ce"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6d01b3b852c812003a52"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:58.029Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:58.029Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(98099161)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b8806ef5417242647b23cf"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6d01b3b852c812003a7d"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:58.106Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:58.106Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(87539171)
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b8806ef5417242647b23d0"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("55ed6cffb3b852c81200391d"),
            "type" : NumberLong(1),
            "status" : "approved",
            "date_created" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:58.229Z"),
            "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:47:58.229Z"),
            "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(78085842)
        }
    ],
    "media" : [ ],
    "template_id" : ObjectId("5626c6c3b3b852bc31007ad6"),
    "title_en" : "3D Modeling I",
    "group_id" : ObjectId("563cc6993764872c268b45d5"),
    "user_slots" : [
        "15:30"
    ],
    "date_start" : ISODate("2016-02-07T20:00:00Z"),
    "date_finish" : ISODate("2016-03-05T20:00:00Z"),
    "place_id" : null,
    "points" : null,
    "date_created" : ISODate("2015-11-06T15:26:17.468Z"),
    "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-02-17T14:01:07.769Z"),
    "shard_location_id" : NumberLong(84354891),
    "shifted" : 5,
    "title_hy" : "3D մոդելավորում I",
    "public_access" : "0",
    "location_access" : [
        NumberLong(0)
    ],
    "description_hy" : "",
    "description_en" : "",
    "min_age_access" : "",
    "max_age_access" : "",
    "max_users" : ""
}
```

Comment: Can you track down the query you are running in the logs? It will still complete even after you time out on the client side, and then you can see how long it is taking to return, may give some more insight.  Also, an explain on the query would be good to see too

Comment: I have enabled the profiling, it doesn't log anything, all of my queries are under 100ms, however mongotop says that on some collections some operations take 5 seconds, that is  confusing. Didn't try explain, I think profiling should answer the question, isn't it?

Comment: mongotop is just a view of how busy particular collections are, it's a cumulative stat based on all activity in a collection, so not particularly useful for troubleshooting a single query issue.  If your queries are not showing up in the log, then they are not taking >30 seconds and your timeout is being caused by something else.  Time to check to see if the place you are running it from has proper connectivity, see if there's a typo somewhere etc. especially if this works quickly when you run it manually

Comment: it always work when I run it second time with a slight delay.

Comment: not arguing about what you are seeing, I don't doubt the sequence, more so about what the cause is.  If a query is actually taking that long to run it would definitely show up in the logs - if there are no queries showing up at all with extended times then something weird is going on. I would start looking for something that (for example) kills long running queries, or see if a packet capture shows anything odd about the first run.  Similarly I would try running it manually out of hours, maybe with an explain at least once to see if the same thing happens.